# Application is starting up but metadata tables are not created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to learn Spring Batch 5. My Spring Batch 5 application starts up successfully, it doesn't create metadata tables.

Pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ajaycodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springbatch</name>
    <description>Spring Boot spring batch demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

applciation.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_batch5
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

# meta data table initialization
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS
```

Main File

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@ComponentScan({"com.ajaycodes.config", "com.ajaycodes.service"})
public class SpringbatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbatchApplication.class, args);
    }
```

SampleJob.java

```java
@Configuration
public class SampleJob {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleJob.class);

    @Autowired
    private SecondTasklet secondTasklet;

    // define bean of type job
    @Bean
    Job firstJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step, Step secondStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("First Job", jobRepository)
                // for first step
                .start(step)
                // for next all steps
                .next(secondStep).build();
    }

    // define a step
    @Bean
    Step firstStep(JobRepository jobRepository, Tasklet myTasklet, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder("First Step", jobRepository)
                .tasklet(firstTask(), transactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    // define a tasklet
    private Tasklet firstTask() {
        // task inside the step
        return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("This is first tasklet step");
                return FINISHED;
            }
        };
    }

    // define second step
    @Bean
    Step secondStep(JobRepository jobRepository, Tasklet myTasklet, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new StepBuilder("Second Step", jobRepository)
            .tasklet(secondTasklet, transactionManager)
            .build();
    }

}
```

SecondTasklet.java

```
@Service
public class SecondTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("This is second tasklet step");
        return FINISHED;
    }

}
```

My project is working fine with Java 8 and Spring Batch 4. I am following the [Spring Batch 5.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide), but I am unable to find why metadata tables are not getting created. I am using MySQL as database.

Comment: Please try lowercase: spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found the root cause of the issue. It was due to @Enable batch processing annotation. We don't need it in spring batch 5. After removing it, it generates the meta data tables and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation worked.
We dont need `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation for spring batch default configuration in spring boot 3.
This is mentioned in the [migration guide of Spring Boot 3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes)